# Landsat util error when downloading data

Tags: ubuntu, landsat

I am having trouble when trying to download data using Landsat util. Using the following command:

```
landsat download LC81710792016253LGN01
```

I get the following issue:

```
landsat download LC81710792016253LGN01
LC81710792016253LGN01 is not available on AWS S3 or Google Storage
Time spent : 1.69 seconds
```

I found the scene ID by searching therefore using Landsat-util so I know it is available. Some of the stuff I tried was to update USGS using:

```
pip install -U usgs
```

And to uninstall landsat-util, the update USGS and reinstalling without any luck. Some other forums suggest to use my credentials which might be the issue because when I use:

```
landsat -h
```

I get the following message:

```
--username          USGS Eros account Username (only works if the account has special
                                    inventory access). Username and password as a fallback if the image
                                    is not found on AWS S3 or Google Storage

--password          USGS Eros account Password
```

So I tried the command again with my credentials:

```
jaun@jaun-pc:~$ landsat --username jaun****@gmail.com --password Ja*****9_ download LC81710792016253LGN01
usage: landsat [-h] [--version] {search,download,process} ...
landsat: error: argument subs: invalid choice: 'jaun****@gmail.com' (choose from 'search', 'download', 'process')
```

It might be that I use the --username and --password command wrong but there is nowhere on the internet where I can get examples thereof.

Comment: try with your credentials after `download <image>`...at least that seems to be suggested by the last error message.